# Best MongoDB schema for me

Tags: mongodb

I am currently planning out my MongoDB schema for an upcoming project, and I'm currently stuck.

In this project; the players have skills, collections and a few other things that need to update in realtime. These would need to be constantly updated, so as a player wins a fight in combat for example; their combat skill goes up. As they find a certain item, a collection counts up.

My question is this, what would be the best practice for this? Nested documents or referencing a separate document?

Any feedback on my current schema would be greatly appreciated!

```json
{
    "uuid": "f6ef95fa-913b-400b-bb76-71aba0fd1aed",
    "playerName": "SomeRandomName",
    "coins": 258725.00,
    "exp": ,
    "equipedPet": "",
    "baseHealth": 100,
    "baseDefense": 0,
    "baseStrength": 0,
    "baseSpeed": 100,
    "baseCritChance": 0,
    "baseCritDamage": 0,
    "baseIntelligence": 0,
    "baseSeaCreatureChance": 0,
    "basemagicFind": 0,
    "basePetLuck": 0,
    "effectiveHP": 100,
    "minionsUnlocked": 0,
    "minionSlots": 5,
}
```

Any help you can shed on this matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How many players? How many servers accessing this database? If you need to update multiple servers in real-time with the latest data for each player MongoDB might not be your best choice. Otherwise if the question is 'nested doc or 'joined' collection?' you'll find many answers here on SO discussing that. Sometimes you want to nest it, sometimes you'll split it off, best design your software to be flexible so you can adjust later if requirements change. e.g. you later need to 'atomically' transfer weapons from one player to another - may be easier if they are in a separate collection.

Comment: First off, thank you for replying. Players, we're expecting anywhere between 1000-10,000. May be above, may be below. But that's what we're planning for.

As for multiple servers, technically yes. What would be your advice on an alternative database?

Comment: SO tip: when someone asks for clarification: update your question so everyone else sees your response. For real-time cached data between all your servers take a look at REDIS. Use MongoDB for long-term persistence (save/load) but for real-time updates use redis.